# Entity Framework Core 5: The different between saving use Add(oldItem) and db.Entry(oldItem).State = EntityState.Modified?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I am using Entity Framework Core 5.0.3, .NET 5.0.103, ASP.NET Core 5 Blazor WebAssebmly. I have -

```
// Cập nhật
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateItem(int id, ProjectWorkCategory newItem)
{
    var oldItem = await db.ProjectWorkCategories.FindAsync(id);
    if (oldItem == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    // Mã loại công trình.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newItem.ProjectWorkCategoryCode))
    {
        oldItem.ProjectWorkCategoryCode = newItem.ProjectWorkCategoryCode;
    }

    // Tên loại công trình
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newItem.ProjectWorkCategoryName))
    {
        oldItem.ProjectWorkCategoryName = newItem.ProjectWorkCategoryName;
    }

    // Diễn giải
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newItem.Description))
    {
        oldItem.Description = newItem.Description;
    }

    // Trạng thái theo dõi.
    if (newItem.ActiveStatus != oldItem.ActiveStatus)
    {
        oldItem.ActiveStatus = newItem.ActiveStatus;
    }

    // Người sửa.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newItem.ModifiedBy))
    {
        oldItem.ModifiedBy = newItem.ModifiedBy;
    }
    oldItem.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    //db.ProjectWorkCategories.Add(oldItem);
    db.Entry(oldItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return NoContent();
}
```

What is the different between

```
db.ProjectWorkCategories.Add(oldItem);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

versus

```
db.Entry(oldItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Does [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic) help?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.ProjectWorkCategories.Add(oldItem);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

the above code adds the entity to database. if 'oldItem' has Unique Id, then you will get exception trying to save it, otherwise it would save duplicate record.

```
db.Entry(oldItem).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

this is the correct way to update an entity.

Answer (score 1):

A record will be added to the database when you use the add method. But if you use the 'State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified', your existing record will be edited in the database.

Answer (score 1):

This one is adding a new item, and as mentioned by @Navid it will through an error if it has a unique Id.

```cs
db.ProjectWorkCategories.Add(oldItem);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

If you want to update you should be using `Update` method:

```cs
db.ProjectWorkCategories.Update(oldItem);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This one also can be used for updating an existing item.

```cs
db.Entry(oldItem).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

#### Deep dive:

*Updated to explain the points mentioned by @atiyar comment*

There is a some differences between using `Add`, `Update` methods and changing the entity state `EntityState.Modified`.

When using *(1)*<del>`Add`</del> `Update` method, the framework will start to track this entity as `EntityState.Added` if it has no `Id` assigned, or will track it as `EntityState.Modified` if it has an `Id`.

> **[DbContext.Update Method:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-5.0#overloads)**
> For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the EntityState.Modified state. If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the EntityState.Added state.

*(2)* When using `Update` method the framework will track the entity and all its referenced entities with `EntityState.Modified` flag.

> *(2)* I still think this is valid. Please see [the explanation in this document:](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/modifying-data#dbcontext-update)  Where this method differs from explicitly setting the State property, is in the fact that the context will begin tracking any related entities (such as a collection of books in this example) in the Modified state, resulting in UPDATE statements being generated for each of them. If the related entity doesn't have a key value assigned, it will be marked as Added, and an INSERT statement will be generated.

When using `EntityState.Modified` the framework will track this entity as `EntityState.Modified`. But all referenced entities will be tracked by `EntityState.Unchanged` flag, and you may need to change the state of each referenced entity to `Modified` manually.

Another difference, <del>when calling `SaveChanges()` after `Update` method, only changed values of the entity will be submitted to the DB.</del> But when you call `SaveChanges()` after using `EntityState.Modified` all values will be submitted to the DB since all fields has been marked as `Modified`.

> *(3)* That is my mistake, I used to use [another library](https://entityframework-extensions.net/update-from-query) which we can use to send only modified fields for update, but this is not valid for `EF Update` method.

#### EDIT

With reference to your update method, you can use both `Update` or `EntityState.Modified`. The easy way is to use `Update(entity)`. In some advanced cases when the entity state could be `Detached` (un-tracked) I use `EntityState` flags to check if the entity is attached (tracked) or not, then I do modify its state accordingly.

Finally, instead of avoiding the result of `SaveChangesAsync()` I recommend to check the value and return:

```cs
var success = await db.SaveChangesAsync();

if(success > 0)
    // log or message for success
else
    // log or message for failure
```

Comment: What is best practice in my case (for Insert, Update)?

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but this answer has several incorrect information in it's `Deep dive` section.
(1) `Add` does not track an entity as `Modified` if it has an Id,
(2) `Update` does not always track _all_ referenced entities as `Modified`,
(3) `Update` does not cause only changed values to be submitted to the DB

Comment: Thank you @atiyar for your comment, I've updated my answer to reply for each point, I hope it is better explained now :)

Comment: @LazZiya If you think about it, point.1 itself makes point.2 invalid. You can add a newly created `Child` entity in the child collection. `Update()` will mark it as `Added` (because it has no `Id`) and `SaveChanges()` will insert it. Same it true for a `Parent` reference. Note, this true for database-generated primary key scenario.

Comment: @atiyar I don't see any conflict, both statements are supporting each other, and yes all above statements are true for DB generated primary key scenario.

Comment: @LazZiya Apologies. I overlooked the word `this` in "the framework will start to track this entity as `EntityState.Added` if it has no `Id` assigned" part.

Comment: @atiyar, glad that we are on mutual understanding now ;)

Comment: @LazZiya Yes. Point.2 is not about the entity in hand, its about related entities.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework tracks an entity with a `State` value, which you can check by -

```
var state = db.Entry(myEntity).State;
```

And when you call `SaveChanges()`, EF tries to insert, update or delete an entity based on its `State` value.

**What `Add()` and `EntityState.Modified` do :**

1. The `Add()` method marks an entity as `Added` (sets the `State` value to `EntityState.Added`), whether the entity has a primary key value or not, and when you call `SaveChanges()` the next time, EF will try to insert that entity.
2. `db.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;` sets the `State` value of the entity explicitly to `Modified`, which basically tells EF that "*this entity already exits in database, and has been modified*". Therefore, on the next `SaveChanges()` call EF will try to update the entity with its new values.

**What `Add()` and `EntityState.Modified` will do in your scenario :**

1. You are trying to update an entity not to insert it. For update operation you are not supposed to use the `Add()` method.
2. You fetched an existing entity from the database (and it has its primary key value in it) with -

```
var oldItem = await db.ProjectWorkCategories.FindAsync(id);
```

At this point the entity will be in `Unchanged` state. Then as soon as you set a new value to any of its properties, the entity gets modified and will automatically go in `Modified` state. But then if you call -

```
db.ProjectWorkCategories.Add(oldItem);
```

the `Add()` method will put the entity in `Added` state. At this point calling `SaveChanges()` will throw an exception, because EF is trying to insert an entity which already exists in database (the primary key violation).

3. In your scenario, by setting -

```
db.Entry(oldItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

you are explicitly marking the entity as `Modified`, and on the next `SaveChanges()` call EF will update the entity with its new values. But the thing is, you don't even need the above line. As I mentioned earlier, fetching an existing entity and changing any of its property value will automatically put the entity in `Modified` state. Therefore, after setting the new values you can directly call -

```
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

and your entity will get updated as expected.